# Visualforce - Adding Scroll bar BlockTable

Tags: visualforce, community

I'm displaying my records in a blocktable.  I would like to limit 10 records visible to the user at a time and the user can scroll down to see the rest.  How can I achieve this?  Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out how to freez the header? I have a similar problem and m clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use Apex:Outputpannel with style attribute to show scrollbar.

Here is the working code :

```
   <apex:page controller="inlineEditSupport">
      <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:200px;height:50px" >
       <apex:PageblockTable value="{!dates}" var="account">
      <apex:outputText value="{!account.DateField__c}"/>
      </apex:PageblockTable>
      </apex:OutputPanel> 
     </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can freeze the header?  thanks

Comment: Is there a way to freez the header alone and keep the body scrollable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix header labels in pageBlockTable you can follow these steps:

1)Create two output panels.
2)In the First panel put a pageblocktable with only headers
3)In the Second panel put your row values with attribute headervalues as blank.

This is an alternate cause I haven't found any proper/quick fix of it.

```
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!accountList.size>0}" id="SearchedBlockTable" title="Searched Records">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton value="GoTo Next Page" action="{!processSelected}" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="height:30px">                                
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accountList}" var="tempVar" rows="1">                                    
            <apex:column headerValue="Select All" width="50px" style="height:0px;">
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')" />
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" width="50px" style="height:0px;" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Number" width="50px" style="height:0px;" />                                   
    </apex:pageblockTable>                               
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow: scroll !important; height: 200px !important;" >                                
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountList}" var="item">                                    
        <apex:column headerValue="" width="40px">                                        
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!item.selected}" id="inputId" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="" width="50px" value="{!item.accountDetail.Name}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="" width="50px" value="{!item.accountDetail.AccountNumber}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
                        
</apex:pageBlock>
```

[image: Sample Of Working Result]

Refer: [Reference Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097ROIAY)